# How to submit data using AJAX and POST Method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

How can I post the following form using `Ajax`. When submitting the form that page refreshes and I want to avoid that.

```
<form method="post" action="" > 
    <div class="rp-donation-block checkout_donation" >
        <p class="message"><strong><?php echo $this->get_setting('message'); ?></strong></p>
        <div class="input text">
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" class="input-text text-donation" name="donation-amount">
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $this->get_setting('btn_lable'); ?>" class="button" name="donate-btn">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried both of these with no luck.

```
<form method="post" action="" onSubmit="return false">
<form method="post" action="" action= "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? Because we are not a code writing community. We will review your code and help you with issues. But we will not write your code. Also there are too many ways to actually accomplish that. There are jQuery plugins with do that, maybe you want to take a look at one. I'm not trying to sound mean or anything.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois  I tried 
   `<form method="post" action="" onSubmit="return false">`, `<form method="post" action="" action= "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">` But No Luck

Comment: You need to provide a javascript function or small code for the attribute `onsubmit`.

Comment: Cancel the form submission preventDefault or return false

Comment: @epascarello  how can i use `preventDefault ` on form code

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 1):

A form is not mandatory to post using `Ajax`. You can write an `Ajax` request using just a button click as well.

```
$(function () {
    $('#buttonId').on('click', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: <url_name>, //some php file where you may hit the database and want to modify content
            data:{'post1': <post1value>,'post2': <post2value>},
            datatype: "JSON", // can be html or text as well
            success: function (data) {
                var actualData = $.parseJSON(data); // if in case of JSON
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If you want to invoke only on form submission you can write your `Ajax` like so.

```
$('#formId').on('submit', function (e) {
});
```

On the other side use :

```
$post_1 = $_POST['post1'];
```

To Get `post1` value.

Comment: Thanks! so on button click i have to call `function ()`, what are `post1 and post2` ? i am sorry i am a newbee

Comment: if you want to post any data to the URL so that you can manipulate it then you have to pass them in that way.
Lets say you are doing a login form authentication, you need to pass username and password to compare to the ones in the database; In such cases you will pass those values when login button is clicked.
Hope its clear.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your form element has id of `form` as `<form id="form"...`

```
<script>
// Attach a submit handler to the form
$( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {

// Stop form from submitting normally
event.preventDefault();

// Get some values from elements on the page:
var $form = $( this ),
donate_amount = $form.find( "input[name='donation-amount']" ).val(),
url = $form.attr( "action" );

// Send the data using post
var posting = $.post( url, { amount: donate_amount } );

// Put the results in message div
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var message_returned = $( data ).find( "#message" ); //hope your are returning message, also you can return other things like message type and create message on frontend as accordingly
    $( ".message" ).empty().append( message_returned ); //adding returned message to your message div
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The button you are using to trigger the event that causes the submit of the form via ajax post should not be of type **submit**! Else this will always fail.